# UILabel set framework doesn't work if the value is negative

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel, frame

I have downloaded this project that show a small example regarding paging:

[Paging example project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BykYqH-1gnVnNVhYcElHb00zSzA/edit)

And I have added a label and by using the scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method that is called when any scrolling action takes place I call  a method that resets the x position of the label aded by me. If I let the x position as I receive it than the position change happens as expected, but if I revert the received parameter value to negative than it doesn't work.

Here is the code:
the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>

- (void)pageChanged ;

@end
```

and the .m file:
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController (){

    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    UIScrollView *scroll;
    UILabel *myLabel;
    int curentLabelX;
    int initialLabelX;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // Scroll View

    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    scroll.delegate=self;
    scroll.pagingEnabled=YES;
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width*3, scroll.frame.size.height)];

  // page control
    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 424, 320, 36)];
    pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.numberOfPages=3;
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    pageControl.alpha = 0;
    CGFloat x=0;
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+0, 0, 320, 460)];
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg",i]]];
        [scroll addSubview:image];

        x+=320;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

        [self.view addSubview:pageControl];
    initialLabelX = 100;

    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView{

//    NSLog(@"%@", _scrollView);
    CGFloat viewWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    // content offset - tells by how much the scroll view has scrolled.

    int pageNumber = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - viewWidth/50) / viewWidth) +1;

    pageControl.currentPage=pageNumber;

    int myLabelContentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    NSLog(@"Scroll offset: %d", myLabelContentOffset);
    [self changeLabelOffset:myLabelContentOffset];
}

- (void)changeLabelOffset:(int) byScrollView{
    curentLabelX = byScrollView;
    curentLabelX = -curentLabelX;
    NSLog(@"Label X pos: %d", initialLabelX + curentLabelX);
    [myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(initialLabelX + curentLabelX, 100, 100, 100)];

}

- (void)pageChanged {
    int pageNumber = (int)pageControl.currentPage;
    CGRect frame = scroll.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width*pageNumber;
    frame.origin.y=0;
    [scroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the label changes the position at the same time and speed with the scroll so it is normal for it to appear as it doesn't move at all.